# Python request post doesn't get redirected

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

When I use Chrome to post a from on this website: "http://xh.5156edu.com/index.php", I get redirected to a new page. However, when I use python request module to do the post, like this:

```
r = requests.post("http://xh.5156edu.com/index.php", data="f_key=%B7%AB&SearchString.x=0&SearchString.y=0")
```

the status code is 200 and the content is not what I want. I'am sure the data is the same as the one sent by Chrome. I can not understand what's wrong with the scripts. I also tried to add some headers, which didn't work neither.

Comment: i got everything backwards: the page is not redirecting. the location header is never sent

Comment: @diggusbickus Sorry, probably I didn't clearly state question. Redirection is wanted, but with python scripts I failed to get the redirected page.

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding more headers. Though I don't know which header is critical but with the headers below it works:
`'Host': 'xh.5156edu.com'`, 
`'Connection': 'keep-alive'`,
`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`, 
`'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Mobile Safari/537.36'`

Comment: `content-type` was enough, which is fair for a `POST` request. and if you just `r.get("http://xh.5156edu.com/index.php?f_key=%B7%AB")` it works too.

Answer (score -1):

What you're passing as data are actually query parameters.

This is what you need:

```
import requests
params = {'f_key': '%B7%AB', 'SearchString.x': '0', 'SearchString.y': '0'}
(r := requests.post("http://xh.5156edu.com/index.php", params=params)).raise_for_status()
with open('x.html', 'w') as html:
    html.write(r.text)
```

You can then open x.html to view the response

Comment: If my memory serves me, params parameter is used for query string. I tried your code but it didn't work.

Comment: They are know as "query parameters" but can also be applied to POST. When I run this code I get a viable HTML page. I don't understand it though because it's in Chinese